# How to get the value of an input radio button and do something based on answer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I'm essentially making a 10 question quiz. I know there's a ton of ways out there to do this and lots of answers on how to get the value of the input radio button, but I just can't quite figure it out! I'm using Foundation 5's Abide Validation for the "required" attribute and the "on('valid.fndtn.abide')", which is just making sure an answer is selected right now.

HTML

```
<h2>Choose one answer:</h2>
<div class="radio">
    <div class="input-radio"><input type="radio" name="question_10" value="Wrong" id="option_37" required><label for="option_37">Answer 37</label></div>
    <div class="input-radio"><input type="radio" name="question_10" value="Wrong" id="option_38" required><label for="option_38">Answer 38</label></div>
    <div class="input-radio"><input type="radio" name="question_10" value="Wrong" id="option_39" required><label for="option_39">Answer 39</label></div>
    <div class="input-radio"><input type="radio" name="question_10" value="Correct" id="option_40" required><label for="option_40">Answer 40</label></div>
</div>
```

Javascript (sans other stuff) that I have now. Right now this is returning "No" even if I select the right answer. If I make all the answers "Correct", it will return "Yes".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-prepare').on('valid.fndtn.abide', function(e) {
        var answer10 = $("input[name='question_10']").val();

        if (answer10 === "Correct") { alert("Yes!"); } 
        else { alert("No!"); 
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

EDIT: Removed second part of the question, as I see it could be it's own question in itself. As per the answer, I was missing the :checked part of my input variable. Thanks!

Comment: I get the feel that your question is more along the lines of "help me built out my function" than any explicit questions.  Is there something specific that can be answered for you as opposed to "help me make it work"?

Comment: Note that I have only answered the first part of your question below (properly getting the value of the radio button). The second part (making this code modular enough to handle more questions) should (in my opinion) be a separate question once you have tried to work it out yourself. As a lead-in for you, try looking at jQuery's `.each()` method, and enumerate over your `.radio` divs, getting the value of the checked radio button within and pushing it to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.val()` method will only return the value of the first element when a collection is returned by the selector, so you are always retrieving the value of the first input with name equal to question_10.

To properly retrieve the value you are after you need to limit your selector to only return the checked element, like this:

```
$("input[name='question_10']:checked").val();
```

Comment: Thank you winterblood, this gives me a really great place to move forward. I was really getting stuck on this bit. I'm going to mark this as the answer and work on it more.